# How to edit a user ID comment or set a new default user ID in GnuPG?

Tags: gnupg

I would like to either remove a user ID or update its comment or at least make another one the default. This is because it contains a comment that has a stupid typographic error. Like:

```
gpg> list

pub  4096R/xxxxxxxx  created: yyyy-mm-dd  expires: yyyy-mm-dd  usage: SCEA
                     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
sub  4096R/xxxxxxxx  created: yyyy-mm-dd  expires: yyyy-mm-dd  usage: SEA 
[ultimate] (1). My Name (comment with a stupid typo) <my-primary@email-address>
[ultimate] (2)  My Name <my-primary@email-address>
[ultimate] (3)  My Name <my-second@email-address>
```

How can I remove `(1)` or make `(2)` the main and default user ID. Everyone that imports my key sees `(1)`. I tried to use `--edit-key` with `primary 2`, but all I get is

> Please select exactly one user ID.

What to do?

Comment: Please be aware that this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow; I voted for migration to Super User.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to select the user ID to edit before running those commands. If you want to remove the first user ID, press <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>, which will highlight the first user ID with a star `*` between the number and user ID:

```
[ultimate] (1)* My Name (comment with a stupid typo) <my-primary@email-address>
[ultimate] (2)  My Name <my-primary@email-address>
[ultimate] (3)  My Name <my-second@email-address>
```

Now run `deluid` to delete it. You can also select multiple user IDs to delete at once. Similarly, to change the default user ID, select the new default (in the unmodified user ID list of your question, by pressing <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>) and run `primary`.
Use <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> again to deselect.

You cannot edit a user ID (including it's comment). Deleting it also might not be what you want to achieve, if the key was already sent to the key server network, it will simply be merged again next time your receive the key from there (also, others will still see it). Instead, revoke it running `revuid` (not <strike>`revkey`</strike> as indicated in the first revision of this post), which will not delete it but mark it as superseded (which is something that will be synchronized throughout the key server network).

Comment: But if I revoke the key, it will be revoked for all associated user ids (my two e-mail addresses), or not? I.e. I will have to create an entirely new key and again have it signed by a number of people to be trusted?

Comment: I wanted to write `revuid`. You cannot only revoke complete keys, but also parts like user IDs. Be aware also revoking/deleting user IDs will (obviously) invalidate incoming certifications for that user ID.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It appears odd to me that you can have multiple user ids for the same e-mail address.

Comment: Technically a user ID is just a string. You cannot have the exactly same user ID string twize, it would be the same ID; but for sure you can use the same mail address multiple times, if there is a (arbitrary minor) difference in the rest of the user ID.